# Background image not including

Tags: css, image, jsf, background

I tried many ways to include a background image in my jsf page but none of them worked. Althought my page recognizes my stylesheet (because it displays the text red), but doesn't include the image. Should I add a mapping resource in my pom.xml ?
    Please advise.

```
This is my folder structure: 

`WebContent
 |-- META-INF
 |-- WEB-INF
 |-- resources
 |    |-- css
 |    |    |-- style.css
 |    |-- images
 |         |-- background.png
 |-- index.xhtml
```

This is what I added in index.xhtml:

```
<h:body class="main">
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="index.css"></h:outputStylesheet>
        <p class="test"> some text </p>
</h:body>
```

And this is my style.css:

```
.main { 
  background-image: url("#{resource['images:background.png']}");               
}
.test {
    color : red;
}
```

Comment: Are you able to reach your resource typing `yourbaseurl/javax.faces.resource/images/background.png`?

Comment: Off topic (although not fully): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used

Answer (score 1):

Solved !!

The problem was that I put `class` attribute instead of `styleClass` to body tag, that is actually a h:body tag.  Thank you all for quick answers :)

Comment: I should have caught that error, but using a browser developer tool so should you ;-). Good it works